# Correct approach to query from one (only) table using association table in Android ROOM

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have been searching the stackoverflow community on how to approach the situation below.
There is a table called APPOINTMENTS which two or more APPOINTMENTS may be LINKED to each other. For instance:

| ID | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10:00am | 12:00pm |
| 2 | 12:00pm | 01:00pm |
| 3 | 04:00pm | 04:30pm |

AppointmentModel.kt

So, APOINTMENTS 1 and 2 may be linked to each other, meaning actually they are some sort of the same event divided into two APOINTMENTS (like work and lunch hours).

I have created an association table to keep those rows linked in a many to many relation:

| ID | LINKED_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

AppointmentJoinRef.kt

I would use those associations in a way that the deletion of ID 1 should cascade to ID 2 (vice-versa).

My POJO looks like this right now:

```
data class ApointmentsPOJO(
   @Embedded var Appointment: AppointmentModel,

   @Relation(
       entity = AppointmentModel::class,
       parentColumn = "ID",
       entityColumn = "ID",
       associateBy = Junction(AppointmentJoinRef::class)
       var linkedAppointments: List<AppointmentModel>
```

From this code, all I can fetch from table is a list containing repetitions of the "parent" Appointment. I am not able to fetch the linked Appointment, and I am afraid it may be not possible from this approach.
I have also tried to mess it up changing parentColumn and entityColumn both in the Relation and in the Junction parameters.

My question is: What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the columns used within the association table by using the **parentColumn** (`ID`) and **entityColumn**(`LINKED_ID`) parameters of the Junction.

So something like:-

```
@Relation(
    entity = AppointmentModel::class,
    parentColumn = "ID",
    entityColumn = "ID",
    associateBy = Junction(AppointmentJoinRef::class, parentColumn="ID",entityColumn="LINKED_ID)
    var linkedAppointments: List<AppointmentModel>
```

**Additional**

Re comment

> Did you try that in actual code? I have tried and got the same result.

Here's a working demo, noting that cascading of deletions (and updates to the keys) is handled by SQLite.

**Database code**

```
@Entity
data class AppointmentModel(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long?=null,
    var start: String,
    var end: String,
    var name: String
)


@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["id","linked_id"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = AppointmentModel::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class AppointmentJoinRef(
    var id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    var linked_id: Long
)

data class AppointmentsPOJO(
    @Embedded
    var appointmentModel: AppointmentModel,
    @Relation(
        entity = AppointmentModel::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = AppointmentJoinRef::class,
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "linked_id"
        )
    )
    var linkedAppointments: List<AppointmentModel>
)


@Database(entities = [AppointmentModel::class,AppointmentJoinRef::class], exportSchema = false, version =  1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAO(): AllDAO

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance =  Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"appointments.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}


@Dao
interface AllDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(appointmentModel: AppointmentModel): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(appointmentJoinRef: AppointmentJoinRef): Long
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM appointmentModel")
    fun getAllAppointmentsWithLinkedAppointments(): List<AppointmentsPOJO>
    @Delete
    fun deleteAppointment(appointmentModel: AppointmentModel): Int
}
```

**Activity Code to Demo**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAO
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAO()

        val a1id = dao.insert(AppointmentModel(1,"10:00 am","12:00 pm","A1"))
        val a2id = dao.insert(AppointmentModel(2,"12:00 pm","01:00 am","A2"))
        val a3id = dao.insert(AppointmentModel(3,"04:00 pm","04:30 pm","A3"))
        val a4id = dao.insert(AppointmentModel(4,"04:30 pm","05:00 pm","A3"))
        val a5id = dao.insert(AppointmentModel(null,"04:30 pm","05:00 pm","A3"))

        dao.insert(AppointmentJoinRef(a1id,a2id))
        dao.insert(AppointmentJoinRef(a2id,a1id))

        dao.insert(AppointmentJoinRef(a1id,a3id))
        dao.insert(AppointmentJoinRef(a2id,a4id))

        dao.insert(AppointmentJoinRef(a5id,a1id))
        dao.insert(AppointmentJoinRef(a5id,a2id))
        dao.insert(AppointmentJoinRef(a5id,a3id))
        dao.insert(AppointmentJoinRef(a5id,a4id))

        logAll("_STG001")
        dao.deleteAppointment(AppointmentModel(a3id,"WHATEVER","WHATEVER","WHATEVER"))
        logAll("_STG002")
        dao.deleteAppointment(AppointmentModel(a1id,"DOESNOTMATTER","DOESNOTMATTER","DOESNOTMATTER"))
        logAll("_STG003")

    }

    fun logAll(suffix: String) {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        val TAG = "APPMNT"
        for (a in dao.getAllAppointmentsWithLinkedAppointments()) {
            sb.clear()
            for (la in a.linkedAppointments) {
                sb.append("\n\tLinked Appointment: ${la.name} Starts @ ${la.start} Ends @ ${la.end}")
            }
            Log.d(
                TAG + suffix,
                "Appoinment is ${a.appointmentModel.name} " +
                        "starting at ${a.appointmentModel.start} " +
                        "ending at ${a.appointmentModel.end} " +
                        "it is linked to ${a.linkedAppointments.size} other appointments, they are:- ${sb}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
2022-12-02 06:23:32.285 D/APPMNT_STG001: Appoinment is A1 starting at 10:00 am ending at 12:00 pm it is linked to 2 other appointments, they are:- 
        Linked Appointment: A2 Starts @ 12:00 pm Ends @ 01:00 am
        Linked Appointment: A3 Starts @ 04:00 pm Ends @ 04:30 pm
2022-12-02 06:23:32.285 D/APPMNT_STG001: Appoinment is A2 starting at 12:00 pm ending at 01:00 am it is linked to 2 other appointments, they are:- 
        Linked Appointment: A1 Starts @ 10:00 am Ends @ 12:00 pm
        Linked Appointment: A3 Starts @ 04:30 pm Ends @ 05:00 pm
2022-12-02 06:23:32.285 D/APPMNT_STG001: Appoinment is A3 starting at 04:00 pm ending at 04:30 pm it is linked to 0 other appointments, they are:- 
2022-12-02 06:23:32.285 D/APPMNT_STG001: Appoinment is A3 starting at 04:30 pm ending at 05:00 pm it is linked to 0 other appointments, they are:- 
2022-12-02 06:23:32.285 D/APPMNT_STG001: Appoinment is A3 starting at 04:30 pm ending at 05:00 pm it is linked to 4 other appointments, they are:- 
        Linked Appointment: A1 Starts @ 10:00 am Ends @ 12:00 pm
        Linked Appointment: A2 Starts @ 12:00 pm Ends @ 01:00 am
        Linked Appointment: A3 Starts @ 04:00 pm Ends @ 04:30 pm
        Linked Appointment: A3 Starts @ 04:30 pm Ends @ 05:00 pm
        
        
        
        
2022-12-02 06:23:32.291 D/APPMNT_STG002: Appoinment is A1 starting at 10:00 am ending at 12:00 pm it is linked to 1 other appointments, they are:- 
        Linked Appointment: A2 Starts @ 12:00 pm Ends @ 01:00 am
2022-12-02 06:23:32.291 D/APPMNT_STG002: Appoinment is A2 starting at 12:00 pm ending at 01:00 am it is linked to 2 other appointments, they are:- 
        Linked Appointment: A1 Starts @ 10:00 am Ends @ 12:00 pm
        Linked Appointment: A3 Starts @ 04:30 pm Ends @ 05:00 pm
2022-12-02 06:23:32.291 D/APPMNT_STG002: Appoinment is A3 starting at 04:30 pm ending at 05:00 pm it is linked to 0 other appointments, they are:- 
2022-12-02 06:23:32.292 D/APPMNT_STG002: Appoinment is A3 starting at 04:30 pm ending at 05:00 pm it is linked to 3 other appointments, they are:- 
        Linked Appointment: A1 Starts @ 10:00 am Ends @ 12:00 pm
        Linked Appointment: A2 Starts @ 12:00 pm Ends @ 01:00 am
        Linked Appointment: A3 Starts @ 04:30 pm Ends @ 05:00 pm
        
        
        
        
2022-12-02 06:23:32.299 D/APPMNT_STG003: Appoinment is A2 starting at 12:00 pm ending at 01:00 am it is linked to 1 other appointments, they are:- 
        Linked Appointment: A3 Starts @ 04:30 pm Ends @ 05:00 pm
2022-12-02 06:23:32.299 D/APPMNT_STG003: Appoinment is A3 starting at 04:30 pm ending at 05:00 pm it is linked to 0 other appointments, they are:- 
2022-12-02 06:23:32.300 D/APPMNT_STG003: Appoinment is A3 starting at 04:30 pm ending at 05:00 pm it is linked to 2 other appointments, they are:- 
        Linked Appointment: A2 Starts @ 12:00 pm Ends @ 01:00 am
        Linked Appointment: A3 Starts @ 04:30 pm Ends @ 05:00 pm
```

- as expected

Comment: Hey @MikeT. Thanks for the answer. Did you try that in actual code? I have tried and got the same result.

Comment: @RamonBarros no I hadn't. However the answer now includes a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if this is the best answer, but this is how I solved this issue for now.

I have written another POJO

```
data class LinkedAppointmentPojo (
    @Embedded val model: AppointmentJoinRef,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "LINKED_ID",
        entityColumn = "ID"
    )
    val linkedAppointments: List<Appointment>
)
```

So the AppointmentPojo is now:

```
data class ApointmentsPOJO(
   @Embedded var Appointment: AppointmentModel,

   @Relation(
       entity = AppointmentModel::class,
       parentColumn = "ID",
       entityColumn = "ID"
   )
       var linkedAppointments: List<LinkedAppointmentPojo>
)
```

I can find the list of appointment linked to another appointment by chaining `appointmentPojo.linkedAppointments[index].linkedAppointments` and it feels too long. Still it is a solution and I am now unblocked.

Comment: I think your issue(s) may be with the function you are using in the @Dao annotated class/interface anyway I've updated the answer with a working demo that also incidentally cascades deletions (as far as they probably should).